# Is it more heimish to say "Google" or "Giggle"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am concerned that saying "Google" (גוגל) is chukat ha-goyim and that I should definitely be saying "Giggle" (גיגל) instead.

Kal v'chomer, I have heard many, l'havdil, Modern Orthodox and secular Jews saying "Google."

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ask a gitte shaileh und a gitte kasheh.

Mimaileh, it's nuhr a Hungarian yid that says "a Gigel." Sez nusich kulei alma to say "a Gugel."

Ba-soif, a yid should only mention Gugel to say that the internet is a treifene medineh, not chas ve shulem because a yid is surfink der web.

A Freilichen Shishin Pirim.

Answer (score 4):

It's more hymish to say giggle but more heimish to say google

Comment: 1,000-point matenas l'vyonim for you (unfortunately, bounties are not awardable after Purim...)

Answer (score 1):

Among many Jews, for whom the internet is pas nisht, they don't know from "Google". So, if you said, "I'm looking for something on Google", they would think you meant to say you're looking for something in the kugel."

On the other hand, some people pronounce "kugel" as "kigel", so you could run into the same problem.

In my opinion, stay away from the internet altogether, and eat more kugel or kigel. This way, there's no concern and no confusion.